# Let CvCameraViewListener2.onCameraFrame() return a static image

Tags: opencv, camera, android

```
Mat specifiedFrame;

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height)
{
specifiedFrame=new Mat();
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
{
if(condition)
{
specifiedFrame=inputFrame.gray();
}
return specifiedFrame;
}
```

When specifiedFrame is a empty Mat, the screen shows total balck which I can understand, but after specifiedFrame=inputFrame.gray() why screen still shows black?
If I directly return inputFrame.gray() screen shows correctly.

Coding with Eclipse on opencv4Android 2.4.11, running on Android 4.4 and 5.0.

Comment: Are you re-displaying your image after setting the value to inputFrame.gray()?

Comment: As my code, I don't think I should do any more re-dispaly thing. Do I miss something obvious?

Comment: Is (condition) being met?, because if not, specifiedFrame will never = inputFrame.gray().

Comment: Absolutely have met. In fact, I have log output inside the if(condition) part, and I also checked specifiedFrame.toString() is not a blank Mat object. It's a height*width, with some parameters within Mat object.

Comment: Check if inputFrame.toString and specifiedFrame.toString are the same, if they are, I think the problem is probably in the code that you return specifiedFrame to, which I assume is the code that displays the mat to screen?

Comment: Also checked that before, the equals() method return false all the time. I've heard that inputFrame.gray() is a subMat which continuously refresh itself, but don't know how to prove this maybe-rumor since I only get a black screen.